# AS3 Extended Jump when Holding Button

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So my mario project must include a staple of Mario's movement, and that of course is the option to jump a short height or a fairly large one. As we all know, holding down the jump button makes him jump higher, that's what my goal is here. In my case, that button is X and I am unsure of how to do that.

This is currently my unsuccessful attempt, and gravity is set to 0.87 by default in my variables.

This is in my keyDownHandler (when the key is pressed)

```
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.X && onGround == true)
        {
            vy +=  jumpForce;
            holdJump = true;
            onGround = false;

            if(holdJump == true && onGround == false)
            {
                _mario.y += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                vy = vy + (grav * 0.20);
                holdJump = false;
            }
```

This is in my keyUpHandler (when the key is not pressed/let go)

```
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.X)
        {
            if (holdJump == false)
            {
                accy = 0;
                gravity = 0.80;
                incSpeedY = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use standard `vy=vyLast-g*(t-tLast)`, and just set `vyLast` to `min(0,vyLast)` when jump key is released, and set it to jump starting speed when jump key is pressed on the ground.

Comment: Sorry, I've only been studying AS3 for about a month, I'm not quite sure what you mean by this, perhaps you could use it in code as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've extended my comment.

> You can use standard `vy=vyLast-g*(t-tLast)`, and just set `vyLast` to `min(0,vyLast)` when jump key is released, and set it to jump starting speed when jump key is pressed on the ground.

Here is the sample Adobe Air application with jumping red circle. It implements the logics that I've described into the comment:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"                
                       >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.utils.getTimer;
            import mx.graphics.SolidColor;
            public var marioY:Number = 0; //jump height above ground (meters)
            public var g:Number = -9.81; //meter/(second^2)
            public var lastTime:Number = NaN;
            public var lastVerticalSpeed:Number = 0;//speed of a flight -meters/second
            public var jumpSpeed:Number = 10;//initial jump speed - meters/second
            public var timeRatio:Number = 1000;//milliseconds in a second
            public var heightRatio:Number = 50; //pixels/meter

            protected function get landed():Boolean{
                return marioY <= 0 && lastVerticalSpeed <= 0;
            }

            protected function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
                if(event.keyCode==Keyboard.UP && landed){
                    lastVerticalSpeed = jumpSpeed;
                    trace('fly!');
                }               
            }

            protected function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
                if(event.keyCode==Keyboard.UP){
                    lastVerticalSpeed = Math.min(0,lastVerticalSpeed);
                    trace('fall!');
                }

            }

            protected function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void{
                if(!isNaN(lastTime)){
                    var deltaTime:Number = (getTimer() - lastTime)/timeRatio;                   
                    marioY+=lastVerticalSpeed*deltaTime;
                    if(landed){
                        lastVerticalSpeed=0;
                        marioY=0;
                    }else{
                        lastVerticalSpeed+=g*deltaTime;
                    }
                }
                mario.y=area.height-marioY*heightRatio-20;  
                lastTime = getTimer();              
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script> 
    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%" keyDown="onKeyDown(event)" keyUp="onKeyUp(event)"
             enterFrame="onEnterFrame(event)" id="area"
             creationComplete="area.setFocus()"
             >
        <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="{new SolidColor(0x0000FF)}"/>
        <s:Ellipse id="mario" width="10" height="10" fill="{new SolidColor(0xFF0000)}"
                   y="100" x="100"
                   />

    </s:Group>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```